# download json using Ion library

Tags: android, json, android-ion

I'am working with ion for download image in my custom list, and it's work perfect! Now I want to use this lib for json. So I tried it, but it's not work.

Anybody know why this sample code return NULL? Or how do it simple?

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Ion.with(this)
                .load("http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_object.json")
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        // do stuff with the result or error
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it give result as NULL? please try System.out.println(result.toString()) and see the output if it throws null pointer exception or shows string representation of the json received

Comment: As I know System.out.println automatically make this function (toString) for arguments.

Comment: And yes, result.toString give Exception

Comment: Just print out out Exception e value and see what error you are getting. I didn't know System.out.println() returns toString() of the object I am glad I learned that :)

Comment: Thanks alot, MAN! You gave me a right way. I looked for exception and I thought of: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: ))) how could I forget it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Check the exception.

derp derp 20 char limit.